# Timthumb: Could not find the internal image you specified

Tags: wordpress, timthumb

I am having the following issue with this version of Timthum: 2.8.10 (running on Wordpress installation - server Ubuntu):

**- When i call images from the server hosting the website i got this error:**

A TimThumb error has occured
The following error(s) occured:

```
Could not find the internal image you specified.
```

Query String : src=http://my-host.it/wp-content/files_mf/1346848579prog_no_pic.png
TimThumb version : 2.8.10

If i copy/paste http://my-host.it/wp-content/files_mf/1346848579prog_no_pic.png in the browser i can get the image...

**- When i call image from external sites it works fine.**
I have enabled:

```
define ('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES', TRUE);
```

at line 33.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the document root wasn't being set correctly, due to my virtual host setup.

I had to add the correct one in `timthumb-config.php`

```
define('LOCAL_FILE_BASE_DIRECTORY', "/home/www/mysite/");
```

Answer (score 2):

This two steps worked for me:

- Set to *true* ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES, in line ~33:

`if(! defined('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES') ) define ('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES', TRUE);`

- comment line ~212

`//$this->src = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?' . $this->myHost . '/i', '', $this->src);`

---

Source:
https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/issues/detail?id=363#c23

Answer (score 1):

I just got over this problem which, in my case, had to do with the file path having a tilde in it.

Here's a link the solution I found:

http://elementdesignllc.com/2012/01/how-to-fix-timthumb-using-a-virtual-directory-url-contains-tildes/comment-page-1/#comment-7418

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Multisite installation of WordPress (3.5.1). The following fixed it:

In *functions.php* change

```
function get_image_url($img_src="") {
if($img_src!="") $theImageSrc = $img_src;
else $theImageSrc = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
global $blog_id;
if (isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0) {
    $imageParts = explode('/files/', $theImageSrc);
    if (isset($imageParts[1])) {
        $theImageSrc = '/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $imageParts[1];
    }
}
echo $theImageSrc;
```

}

to

```
function get_image_url($img_src="") {
if($img_src!="") $theImageSrc = $img_src;
else $theImageSrc = strstr(wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)), "/wp-content");
global $blog_id;
if (isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0) {
    $imageParts = explode('/files/', $theImageSrc);
    if (isset($imageParts[1])) {
        $theImageSrc = '/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $imageParts[1];
    }
}
echo $theImageSrc;
```

}

*Note:* The only actual modification happens in the 3rd line (bold):
$theImageSrc = **strstr(** wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)) **, "/wp-content")**;

Comment: This works but this is really stupid ... why does timthumb need this?

Answer (score 0):

First let me know are you using WordPress Multisite? If yes then you dont need edit anything in timthumb.php me do like it

This is what I have done to get timthumb to work with multisite. You need to add this code to your theme's functions.php file

```
<?php function get_image_path($src) {
global $blog_id;
if(isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0) {
$imageParts = explode('/files/' , $src);
if(isset($imageParts[1])) {
$src = '/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $imageParts[1];
}
}
return $src;
}
?>
```

And then where the timthumb script is used in the theme, you need to modify to this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/includes/timthumb.php?q=100&w=180&h=200&zc=1&a=t&src=<?php echo get_image_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postImage', true)); ?>" alt="" />
```

where postImage is the name of the meta field the holds the image URL.

have a nice.